# Use yum to install only pre-downloaded files

Tags: centos, software-installation

I am trying to install certain applications in a CentOS 7 machine. I have Java already downloaded in another machine and copied to this machine. I am trying to install Java, but want to make sure that it is not downloading anything.

I am looking for a way to make sure that the CentOS machine do not download anything. Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: What is the need to use yum, but not to use rpm to install already downloaded packages? 
rpm -Uvh <package file-name>

Comment: It's an `rpm` or a `tar` archive?

Comment: The only way to make sure that `yum` doesn't download anything is to have the rpm and all of its dependencies in one folder and then cd into the folder and install them all with `yum localinstall *.rpm`.